# Checking javascript variables in phpunit

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpunit

I am trying to write the phpunit test case for login page using zf2.

In my application the complete view is generated using javascript(Extjs). So there is only few html tag. In this case I cannot use **assertQueryContentContains** to check whether user is logged in or not. But the javascript variables are populating with the logged in username and other stuffs.  So is it possible to check whether **assertQueryContentContains** some value in javascript variables?